# $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, if $3|(a+b)$, then $3|(a-b)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm getting stuck towards the beginning of proving whether or not this is true.

So far, I understand that if $(a+b)$ is divisible by $3$ then $(a+b)=3k$, and the same for $(a-b)=3l$, for some $k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$. I also have $(a+b) ̸= 0$, and the same for $(a-b)$.

After doing some reworking of the equations and such, I can get $b=3(l-k)$ and $a=\frac{(3(l+k))}{2}$. This is where I'm getting stuck and I'm not sure if it's because I'm taking things the wrong direction.

Comment: $a=2,b=1$ is a counterexample

Comment: So, I have that as well. Would that counterexample be sufficient enough to prove that the statement is false?

Comment: Given that your statement says "**for all** $a$,$b$", a counterexample is sufficient to disprove the claim.

Comment: Since the quantifier used at the beginning is "for all" so a single counterexample is sufficient to claim that the statement Is false.

Comment: Understood. Well, I guess I was just trying to overcomplicate things then. Thanks a ton!

Comment: $a=3k+1$ and $b=3n+2$.  Is that enough for counterexamples?

Comment: Did you mean $a-\color{red}2b?$

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the comments to the question, there are plenty of counterexamples to show this is not true (such as $a=2, b=1; 3$ divides $2+1$ but not $2-1).$  On the other hand, if $3|a+b$ then $3|a+b-3b=a-\color{red}2b.$